# What is PersistedOffset

Tags: flutter

I’m getting the message “persistedOffset is in an unexpected state” in flutter web (DartPad.dev), and I’m trying to understand what “PersistedOffset” even is, so I can (personally) find out how to fix it.

I won’t give the code I used to achieve it because I have no idea which of the over 600 lines are causing the problem, and because I am looking for a general explanation on what it is anyway.

I’ve tried googling to find out what it is, but I only found out that it maybe has something to do with navigation, but no explanation what it is.

Comment: **PersistedOffset is a class in Flutter that is used to store the position of a scrollable widget so that it can be restored later. It is usually used in conjunction with the ScrollController class**.

Comment: Since there’s nothing scrollable in the entire app, I’m very confused why I’m getting that message then…